# Interpreting matrices with SVD

Tags: linear-algebra

I saw this on this interpretation on the wikipedia page but I don't see how the SVD is able to apply to this? In particular the rowspace part? Thanks!

"Intuitively, given a matrix A, the action of the matrix A on a vector x will return a linear combination of the columns of A weighted by the coordinates of x as coefficients. Another way to look at this is that it will (1) first project x into the row space of A, (2) perform an invertible transformation, and (3) place the resulting vector y in the column space of A. Thus the result y = A x must reside in the column space of A. See singular value decomposition for more details on this second interpretation.[clarification needed]"

Comment: It's easier to understand the interpretation if you consider the "skinny" SVD instead, where $V^T$ is a projection (in a sense) onto the row space